# Ordenação de vetor

Tags: lua, classificação, array, lua-table

Eu estou aprendendo sobre vetores e matrizes, e já há um bom tempo não consigo resolver uma questão da forma correta.

O enunciado diz: Dado algum vetor, ordene-o em forma sequencial(numérica).

Exemplo:

```
Entrada:{1,2,2,3,3,4}

Saída:{1,2,3,4,2,3}
```

Eu fiz um código que deve pegar qualquer vetor dado pelo usuário, ordenar ele em forma crescente e depois re-ordena em forma sequencial numérica. Porém, o problema é que meu código sempre erra na primeira sequência, deixando o maior número no final do vetor e não no seu lugar devido(no final da primeira sequência).

Exemplos:

```
Entrada:{1,2,2,3,3,4}

Saída:{1,2,3,2,3,**4**}

Entrada:{1,2,5,2,5,3,3,4}

Saída:{1,2,3,2,3,4,5,**5**}

vetor = {}
tamanho = #vetor
function CriarVetor ()
    print("Insira o tamanho do vetor")
    tamanho = io.read("*number")
    print("Insira os valores do vetor(ordenados ou nao)")
    for i=1,tamanho do
        vetor[i] = io.read("*number")
    end
end
function Ordenar ()
    for j=1,tamanho-1 do
        for k=j+1, tamanho do
            if vetor[j] > vetor[k] then
                vetor[j],vetor[k] = vetor[k],vetor[j]
            end
        end
    end
end
function ReOrdenar ()
    for j=1,tamanho-1 do
        if vetor[j] < vetor[j+1] and vetor[j] == vetor[j-1] then
            vetor[j],vetor[j+1] = vetor[j+1],vetor[j]
        end
    end
end
CriarVetor()
Ordenar()
ReOrdenar()
for b=1, tamanho do
    print("A posicao "..b.." do vetor vale: "..vetor[b])
end
```

Comment: Explica melhor o que é ordenar crescente e sequencial. Isto não faz sentido pra mim. Não consigo imaginar para que serve esse `ReOrdenar()`.

Comment: Ordernar crescente: Deixa o valores dentro do vetor em ordem crescente. 1,2,3,4,5 ou  1,2,3,3,3,4,5 ou 1,2,2,3,3,4,5 
Ordenar Sequencial: Deixa os valores em sequencia do menor para o maior (Sem nenhuma repetição seguida).
1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,1 ou 1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5 ou 1,2,3,4,2,3
Re ordenar deveria ser a função onde o vetor sairia da forma Crescente e iria para a forma sequencial.